# Old DNS GPO being applied and can't find which one

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, adapter

Our active directory is old and upgraded from 2003 to 2008r2. Now we have a hybrid of 2008 r2, 2012 r2 (on a different site only) and 2016 (we're headed there anyway).

We created Sub OU's for each company. My problem is one of these OU's was tested in the past with the "Append these DNS suffixes" option. As far as I know and I went through all of the applied GPO's there isn't any GPO that has this settings. Also, it's not like the option "Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes" is greyed out…

This happens on newly installed computers which we install from the ISO and not a custom image

I don't know where else to search, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Run gpresult on the machine and look at the settings being applied and from which GPO.

Comment: I posted the question after checking my gpo's with gpresult /h and nothing I also went to the registry to see that but it didn't come from there. I did see the searchlist parameter in the registry filled with my domain and this wasn't done manually...

Comment: Could it be that the DNS suffix search list is coming from DHCP?

Comment: It look like you were right, this does seem to come from the DHCP but I don't have option 119 just option 15... weird